# Need a better understanding of installing AWS-Nuke for Mac

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, devops, aws-nuke

Im sure this this just a lack of knowledge on my end but im having a hard time understand how to install aws-nuke following there documentation. I have downloaded the latest release but install instructions are not so clear for me [https://github.com/rebuy-de/aws-nuke#:~:text=Use%20Released%20Binaries,Run%20%24%20aws%2Dnuke%2Dv2.16.0%2Dlinux%2Damd64](https://github.com/rebuy-de/aws-nuke#:%7E:text=Use%20Released%20Binaries,Run%20%24%20aws%2Dnuke%2Dv2.16.0%2Dlinux%2Damd64)

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: There is nothing to install there. You download the latest release and extract the executable. You create a config file as it is specified in the [usage](https://github.com/rebuy-de/aws-nuke#usage) and run `aws-nuke -c nuke-config.yml`. If you have profiles set up in your `aws` CLI, you might want to use one `aws-nuke -c config.yml --profile myprofile`.  By defualt `aws-nuke` wont remove anything as long as you don't  add `--no-dry-run` argument, so it is safe to play around with it.

Comment: I completely understand downloading the latest release but not clear on how to extract the executable, it seems everything I try fails.  Again im on a mac and really unfamiliar with this process

Answer (score 1):

On a Mac you can run `aws-nuke` using the following steps:

1. Open a terminal (`Command` + `Space` and write terminal)
2. Grab the latest version of the `aws-nuke`. Currently the latest version is `2.17.0` but obviously this will change in the future. In order to download `aws-nuke`, we can run the following command:

- For M1 Mac:

```
wget https://github.com/rebuy-de/aws-nuke/releases/download/v2.17.0/aws-nuke-v2.17.0-darwin-arm64.tar.gz
```

- For intel Mac:

```
wget https://github.com/rebuy-de/aws-nuke/releases/download/v2.17.0/aws-nuke-v2.17.0-darwin-amd64.tar.gz
```

3. Extract the package using the following command (note: use `amd64` instead of `arm64` if you are on an intel Mac):

```
tar -xvf aws-nuke-v2.17.0-darwin-arm64.tar.gz
```

4. Create a `config.yml` file with the following content and place it nearby the extracted executable:

```
regions:
- global

account-blocklist:
- "999999999999" # leave it as it is, since the current version wont work if you don't provide a blocklist

accounts:
  "000000000000": {} # fill in your own AWS account number
```

5. Run the following command:

```
./aws-nuke-v2.17.0-darwin-arm64 -c config.yml
```

This should list the resources which might be deleted. If you are ok with the list, append `--no-dry-run` to the previous command.

Comment: Thank you greatly for this clear run through I was able to look up those command ad get a much better understanding!!